# How to add value into new column based on corresponding value in another column?

Tags: r

This is the sample data with 'y' being the new variable created.

| x | A | B | C | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 | 7 |  |
| B | 5 | 6 | 7 |  |
| C | 3 | 5 | 3 |  |

If the value of column x ="A", I would like the value of col.A to be displayed in column y. And similarly for the "B" & "C" values in column x.

Final result should be something like this.

| x | A | B | C | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 | 7 | 1 |
| B | 5 | 6 | 7 | 6 |
| C | 3 | 5 | 3 | 3 |

Comment: Have you tried `ifelse`, `if_else`/`case_when`? Could you please add what has failed and add data with `dput(head(df,n))`? However, what's the overall point? it seems a pivot might be a better way(?)

Answer (score 0):

A proposition :

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
x   A   B   C
A   1   4   7   
B   5   6   7   
C   3   5   3
"
)

df$y <- paste0("df$",df$x,"[df$x=='",df$x,"']")
df
#>   x A B C               y
#> 1 A 1 4 7 df$A[df$x=='A']
#> 2 B 5 6 7 df$B[df$x=='B']
#> 3 C 3 5 3 df$C[df$x=='C']

df$y <- eval(ivmte:::unstring(df$y))
df
#>   x A B C y
#> 1 A 1 4 7 1
#> 2 B 5 6 7 6
#> 3 C 3 5 3 3

# Created on 2021-01-30 by the reprex package (v0.3.0.9001)
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create_column<-function(){
        y<-numeric(nrow(your_dataframe))
        for (i in 1:nrow(your_dataframe)){
                y[i]<-your_dataframe[i, which(names(your_dataframe)==your_dataframe$x[i])]
        }
        cbind(your_dataframe, y)
}
```

```
create_column()

  x A B C y
1 A 1 4 7 1
2 B 5 6 7 6
3 C 3 5 3 3
>
```

another option with apply:

```
cbind(your_dataframe, y=apply(your_dataframe, 1, function(x){
        x[which(names(x)==x['x'])]
}))
```

```
> your_dataframe
  x A B C y
1 A 1 4 7 1
2 B 5 6 7 6
3 C 3 5 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df$y <- df[-1][cbind(seq(nrow(df)),match(df$x,names(df)[-1]))]
```